# How to use 'use' with Composer autoload in IF Statement

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to use Composer to auto-load the paths to a firebase/php-jwt library which is located on a different directory as my webpage.
Basically, the firebase/php-jwt library is in this path:
`www/lib/vendor/firebase/php-jwt/src/JWT.php` and the page trying to access the library is in this path: `www/api/test.php`

Here is my code to auto-load paths to library using Composer

```
if ($count > 0) {
require '../lib/vendor/autoload.php'; // autoload paths to libraries

// Class from firebase/php-jwt library
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

// create json-web-token (JWT)
$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $secret_key);
}
```

However, I keep getting this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

How do I solve this?

**Edited**
So I have edited my question. My original question initially did not reflect the code within the 'if' block, but now I have updated my question to reflect that. So the problem was that 'use' must be declared in the outermost scope of a file (the global scope). I writing this down so that people know what the problem initially was. Anyways, thanks to all who tried to help in solving my question.

Comment: What happens if you remove the backslash before Firebase?

Comment: Still shows same error after removing the backslash

Comment: Which php version do you use?

Comment: php version 7.0.29

Comment: Can you show the complete error? I din´t can reproduce this error.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE) in C:\wamp64\www\api\test.php on line 56

Comment: Is your code inside a function?

Comment: the above code is inside "if" statement

Comment: Thanks  Nico Haase. I took require '../lib/vendor/autoload.php';  and 'use' outside the if block and it worked

Comment: I have also updated my question to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

So the issue that was causing the error was the 'use' inside the 'if' block. This is because 'use' does the importing at compile time and not runtime, so it cannot be block scoped.

```
require '../lib/vendor/autoload.php'; // autoload paths to libraries

// Class from firebase/php-jwt library
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

if ($count > 0) {
     // create json-web-token (JWT)
    $jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $secret_key);
}
```